# PHP - handling DateTime variables and creating a range

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

I would like to create an array of DateTime variables from a start to a finish date. I am using the following function to create the array of values.

```
<?php 
class utility 
{

    // constructor
    function __construct()
    {

    }

    /* Creates an array of dates in YYYY-MM-DD format
    * INPUT:
    *          @ From
    *          @ To 
    * OUTPUT:
    *          @ ArrayOfDates
    */ 

    function createDateRangeArray($strDateFrom,$strDateTo)
    {
        $aryRange = array();

        $iDateFrom=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateFrom,5,2),     substr($strDateFrom,8,2),substr($strDateFrom,0,4));
        $iDateTo=mktime(1,0,0,substr($strDateTo,5,2),     substr($strDateTo,8,2),substr($strDateTo,0,4));   

        if ($iDateTo>=$iDateFrom)
        {
             array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom)); // first entry
             while ($iDateFrom<$iDateTo)
             {
                 $iDateFrom+=86400; // add 24 hours 
                 array_push($aryRange,date('Y-m-d',$iDateFrom));
             }
        }
        return $aryRange;
     }
  }?>
```

When I ask an array from 2016-01-01 to 2016-01-06 the resulting array is correct:

```
From: 2016-01-01
To: 2016-01-06
Number of dates: 6
2016-01-01,2016-01-02
2016-01-02,2016-01-03
2016-01-03,2016-01-04
2016-01-04,2016-01-05
2016-01-05,2016-01-06
```

**The Problem:**

If the period is from 2016-01-06 to 2016-01-09 the array is completely wrong.

```
From: 2016-01-06
To: 2015-12-31
Number of dates: 0
```

What am I missing?

**Support**

You can test the function using the following code.

```
<?php
    require_once 'utility.php';
    $utility = new utility();

    $yearFrom = 2016; $monthFrom = 01; $dayFrom = 06;
    $yearTo = 2016; $monthTo = 01; $dayTo = 09;

    $from = new DateTime($yearFrom.'-'.$monthFrom.'-'.$dayFrom);
    echo "<div>From: <b>". $from->format('Y-m-d') . "</b> </div>";
    $to = new DateTime($yearTo.'-'.$monthTo.'-'.$dayTo);
    echo "<div>To: <b>" . $to->format('Y-m-d') . "</b> </div>";

    $arrayDate = $utility->createDateRangeArray($from->format('Y-m-d'),$to->format('Y-m-d'));

    echo "<div> Number of dates: " . count($arrayDate) . " </div>" ;

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrayDate)-1  ; $i++)
    {
        echo "<div> " . $arrayDate[$i] . "," . $arrayDate[$i+1] .  " </div>";
    }

?>
```

**EDIT**

I have noticed that if the number of the day is `9` instead of `09` it works...

Comment: You may want to check out The PHP League's [Period](http://period.thephpleague.com/) package. It was created specifically to handle time ranges in PHP.

Comment: Oh nice @BenHarold! I will definitely try this library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're running into a type casting issue when you first instantiate the DataTime objects, as seen in your output where the `To` date is incorrect:

```
From: 2016-01-06
To: 2015-12-31
Number of dates: 0
```

Specifying the from and to variables as strings explicitly instantiates the DateTimes correctly:

```
$yearFrom = '2016'; $monthFrom = '01'; $dayFrom = '06';
  $yearTo = '2016'; $monthTo = '01'; $dayTo = '09';
```

Output:

```
From: 2016-01-06
To: 2016-01-09
Number of dates: 4
2016-01-06,2016-01-07
2016-01-07,2016-01-08
2016-01-08,2016-01-09
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help.